# Electron Child process access bin

Tags: electron, child-process

i am building an application to manage a few services. starting one of these requires running a .sh script 
i am able to run this fine using child_process spwan 
it runs fine during development
but when i package the app for distribution its not able to recognize brew in the system.

`which brew` returns empty 
seems like the child process is not able to locate the bin folder on the distribution package. 
any pointer to a possible fix for this

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
    const ls = spawn('/Users/myapp/./startbash.sh');

    ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    ls.on('close', (code) => {
      console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with MAC OS not having the correct path this can be solved my pointing node to the right path like so

```
process.env["PATH"] = "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin";
```